# How can I iterate over a column to find cells with a specific value and then iterate over those rows?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, worksheet

I want to search through a column (column A) and find all the "Good" files, then I want to create a list of all the data in Column B, the "Corresponding Info About File" that corresponds with the Good files from Column A. Therefore, excluding all the bad files and their corresponding info in the final list

[image]

My code so far returns all the Good items in Column A, but returns ALL the items in Column B, rather than just the ones that correspond with Column A.

```
          Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[sheetSpaces];
        Excel.Range col = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Columns["A:A", Type.Missing];
        Excel.Range colB = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Columns["B:B", Type.Missing];

        foreach (Excel.Range item in col.Cells)
        {
            string text = (string)item.Text;
            if (text == "Good")
            {                 
                Console.WriteLine(text);

                foreach (Excel.Range itemSub in colB.Cells)
                {
                    string textSub = (string)itemSub.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you'll want to iterate through _all_ the rows, then check if column `A` in each row is equal to "Good", if yes, then take the value of column `B` and do something with it

Comment: @maccettura Your method makes a lot of sense, I've edited my script, although now I;m stuck on how to make an if/foreach statement that would return only the Column B items that correspond with the Good items. Right now it is returning only Good items in Column A, but ALL the info in Column B.

Comment: Your latest code isn't my method though.  You shouldn't iterate through the A columns and B columns separately, you should iterate through the _rows_.  So you have one foreach that goes through every _row_.  Then inside that foreach you check `colA == "Good"`, if true then `list.Add(colB);` This is psuedocode obviously

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an if-statement to your loop:

```
if(item.Value().ToString().Contains("Good")){
// do something
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that OP is iterating through only the first column, not the entire row.  So while your if statement would give the OP the match they need, it _would not_ give the value of column B (as requested in the question).